# Is this a possible Leakage current problem

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, diodes, leakage-current

I have a question about the connection circuit between µ-controller and KSZ8851SNL.

[image]

Are the CSN and SO pins of the KSZ8851SNL tolerant inputs?
When Q1 is off, LAN3.3V was 0.9V in actual measurement. I think this is due to the current flowing through the internal protection circuit of KSZ8851SNL from the pull-up resistors of CSN and SO. In this case, is there any problem with the design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem, as the circuit is doing exactly the thing that the datasheet warns about what should not be done.

The datasheet does not say what happens if you do against the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Any idea on what might happen if this is done based on your experience ?

Comment: That's why I said the datasheet does not bother to mention what will happen if the chip is used against the conditions for normal operation. If  chips are used outside normal operating conditions, they don't have to work properly, it might not start properly, it might degrade faster and have shorter life, or it may latch up and damage immediately the next time you turn power on. At least it is leaking current and rising the supply that should be off.

Comment: Yes thank you for the answer. I have accepted the answer. This question is closed. But if possible, I'd like to know what alternate methods can be done to avoid such thing?